# How to retain the time of the countdown timer even when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript

i have countdown timer in java script ,i want to retain the countdown time even when the page is refreshed can you please suggest me what direction i have to follow

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cookies, because they add unnecessary overhead to your page requests.

Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) instead ([compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) ([polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills))):

```
var countdowntimervalue = 100;                            // Some variable
localStorage.setItem('timer_value', countdowntimervalue); // <-- Set the value
```

To get the value at a later point use:

```
var saved_value = localStorage.getItem('timer_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie to set a timestamp, and then reference the timestamp in future page loads.